# How to : Bitonic Sort with OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I' m quite new to openmp and i have this assignment for school.I think the problem is in bitonicMerge.I have been trying a lot of variations and possibilities and the "best solution" i found is the following:

```
`void sort() {
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
       recBitonicSort(0, N, ASCENDING);
  }
}

void recBitonicSort(int lo, int cnt, int dir) {
  if (cnt>1) {
    int k=cnt/2;
     #pragma omp task if(cnt>1024) // elements vary from 2^12 to 2^24
        recBitonicSort(lo, k, ASCENDING);
     #pragma omp task if(cnt>1024)
        recBitonicSort(lo+k, k, DESCENDING);
     #pragma omp taskwait
  bitonicMerge(lo, cnt, dir);
  }
}

void bitonicMerge(int lo, int cnt, int dir) {
  if (cnt>1) {
    int k=cnt/2;
  int i;
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(p)
  {
  #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
      for (i=lo; i<lo+k; i++)
      {
        //printf("Num of threads: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        compare(i, i+k, dir);
      }
  #pragma omp single
  {
    #pragma omp task if(cnt>1024)
      bitonicMerge(lo, k, dir);
    #pragma omp task if(cnt>1024)
      bitonicMerge(lo+k, k, dir);
    }
   }
  }
 }`
```

The code works but has a time cost(Imperative bitonic takes 0.5s, Recursive takes 7-8s with elements=2^20 and maxthreads=8).I am aware that printf prints 1 thread only, probably because recBitonicSort assigns a single thread to bitonicMerge, but i cant find a better solution.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: What's wrong with my bitonicMerge...?